# How to properly set input and label tags?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete the assignment for my class, and I cannot see the mistake in my code. I am enrolled in a Web Technology class at FSCJ, and they used MindTab for each assignment. The task is very simple:

Create a second div element in the web form that encloses a label with the text Phone* associated with the phoneBox control. Within the div element, add an input box with the ID phoneBox, field name custPhone, and placeholder text (nnn) nnn-nnnn. Make custPhone a required field and have any text entry follow the regular expression pattern ^\d{10}$|^(\ (\d{3})\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$. (Note: You can copy the regular expression code from the rb_regex2.txt file.)

and this is my code:

```
        <div>
          <label for="phoneBox">Phone*</label>      
          <input name="custPhone" id="phoneBox" type="number" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" 
            pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3})\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" required />
        </div>
```

The problem is the code has to pass a code validator and is throwing this error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('{{localhost}}/rb_customer.html')
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form input#phoneBox')
assert(elm.get_attribute('placeholder') == '(nnn) nnn-nnnn')


elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form input#phoneBox')
assert(elm.get_attribute('pattern') == '^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$')


driver.close()
```

I had a chat with someone at BrainFuse and he said that the code looks good. I also called the Cengage technical support to see if there was any problem with the site but no. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: At a glance, based on the phone number format, your input field cannot be of type `number`. Type `text` is more appropriate here. Also the error provided doesn't look like an error but the end-to-end test code. Is there any other output from the testing platform?

Comment: Also it looks like you are missing a backslash in front of closing parenthesis  around this section of the regexp: `...{3}\)\s*...`.

Comment: Thank you much for your help. It was the input field text not number. Appreciate your help.